# Efficiency vs Encapsulation: Which is preferred?

Tags: c++, oop

Achieving good encapsulation in a class would be to make sure no outside forces could modify the internals of an object. In C++ this would mean that a class should allocate all objects, that require dynamic allocation, itself. If of such an object a copy has to be made, it would mean that a lot of the internal attributes have to be copied as well (not just the pointers). This could result in a lot of overhead for certain programs. An example is given below:

```
class A { };

class B : public A {
private:
  std::vector< const A* > m_children;
public:
  B( ) : m_children( 0 ) { }

  B( const B& src ) : m_children( src.m_children.size( ) ) { // Make it a copy of src
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < m_children.size( ); i++ )
      // Make a full copy of src element (and all children, not implemented here)
      m_children[ i ] = copyOf( *src.m_children[ i ] ); // Dynamically allocates copy!
  }

  ~B( ){ // Deallocate all children
    while ( !m_children.empty( ) ){
      delete m_children.back( ); // Get last element in array
      m_children.pop_back( ); // Remove last element
    }
  }

  void addChild( const B& child ) {
    m_children.push_back( new B( child ) ); // Notice dynamic allocation
  }
};

B build( int x ) {
  B b;
  if ( x != 0 ) b.addChild( build( x - 1 ) );
  return b;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
  B b = build( 10 ); // Make 10 generations with 1 child each
}
```

Every time a child is added to B, it gets fully allocated again (with all its children). This really provides good encapsulation because whatever the circumstances, the parent is the only one that can actually modify its children (or deallocate the pointers). Also, it is fully responsible for deleting those children upon its own destruction. This is not very efficient in terms of memory management. A lot of additional objects have to be dynamically created and deleted for each build() function.

How there are two possibilities:
Either I'm missing something here, and this could be done by achieving both good encapsulation and efficiency. If this is the case, please tell me.
Or, this is the only way of doing it, and then: Which way is usually preferred; strong encapsulation (with no outside access), or allocating objects outside of the class so memory operations occur less but "the outer world" has access to these pointers and their objects (which is less safe)?

Comment: "Achieving good encapsulation in a class would be to make sure no outside forces could modify the internals of an object." Personally, that's not how I think about it. The purpose of encapsulation is to allow you to enforce *invariants*. If a class needs to be in a valid state, you can make a constructor that builds in that state or throws an exception, and accessors that permit keeping it in a valid state always. It's not about just mindlessly building a wall to encumber users of the class. If there's no invariant to maintain then use a struct not a class, imo.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic memory allocation and pointers to base when it looks like all you store are `B`s?

Comment: You could use move semantics in your addChild() method, which would eliminate  the need to copy your object.

Comment: @NathanOliver This is just a shortened example to demonstrate the design. In a real implementation there could be used multiple different sub-classes of A.

Comment: @Dennis Okay.  Have you though about using a [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)?

Comment: Efficiency is pretty tricky. Sometimes low level optimizations can hurt performance because you reduce parallelism or prevent the compiler from doing optimizations. So what's efficient is usually different from case to case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use move semantics to avoid needless copying. You will need to add a move constructor to your `class B`.

```
class B
{
    B(B&& rhs)
   {
       std::swap(m_children, rhs.m_children);
   }
}
```

Then you can change your `addChild()` function to:

```
class B
{
    void addChild(B child) 
    {
        m_children.push_back( new B( std::move(child) ) );
    }
}
```

Why this works? In you `build()` function you pass a temporary to `addChild()` function. This will invoke the move constructor and you then just move the object onward.

[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62efac98e51ef3da) - with deleted copy constructor, so you see there is no copying involved.

Comment: This would indeed work for the exact example given. However, it means that the temporary passed to addChild() would lose it's children because they are moved. That might be acceptable for this exact program, but not for more general situations. I don't really considerer this to be "better" in terms of design.

Comment: @Dennis In this particular case 'addChild' function could return a reference to the B object in 'm_children'. This way you could still manipulate the object outiside eventhough the original was moved into 'addChild'.